# Wordpress skip latin characters from filename issue

Tags: php, wordpress, character-encoding, image-uploading

I have installed piclone theme in my word press website. it has default add pin with upload image function. my issue is my images name contain some Latin characters, so when i upload image it skips Latin characters from my image name.

Like example my image name is korzyść.jpg it convert that name to korzy.jpg  but i need output like korzyść.jpg to korzysc.jpg

I have tried from last 2 days but not get success.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to want this. Special characters can give all kinds of problems.

An example of how a bowser reads this: [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/html_form_submit.asp?text=korzyść.jpg](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/html_form_submit.asp?text=korzy%C5%9B%C4%87.jpg)

Why does it need to have those characters?

Comment: i need that characters for seo purpose to remain in filename. and for admin side image upload works perfect but this is issue at front side image uploading.

Comment: sorry but you have given me example of display. i do not want to display Latin chars. my issue is it skips Latin chars from my image name when it is upload. so it is issue in php programming side.

Comment: If the upload function is part of the _piclone_ theme I suggest asking the theme developer for support. If the admin does work then the theme is doing something wrong.

Comment: yes but i do not remember from whom i purchase. it is long time ago.

Comment: do you know in wordpress in which file. filename rename code contains ? like it concate random string with  file name